# Where to register selectors in playwright?

Tags: playwright

You can register a custom selector in Playwright via a `selector.register` call. But it doesn't work if you put it in the global setup function. Where should I put it so it would work in every test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Playwright config file is a good place for it, since it gets loaded before every test and before globalSetup as well.

Comment: Indeed it works, thanks! Strangely putting it into the globalSetup doesn't.